# I am new to react native and firebase image upload, and im trying to upload an image selected from the library to firebase storage

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-storage

Trying to capture result.uri from Image picker and store in firebase storage but error keeps popping up.

Am i calling it from firebase config.js wrong?

Dependencies

```
{

  "dependencies": {
...
    "expo": "~46.0.16",
    "firebase": "^9.13.0",
    "..react": "18.0.0",
    "react-native": "0.69.6
}
```

App.js

```
...
export default function App() {

  useEffect(() => {
      getPermission();
  },[]);

  const getPermission = async () => {
    if(Platform.OS !== 'web'){
      const { status } = await ImagePicker.requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync();
      if(status !== 'granted'){
        alert('Sorry, we need camera roll permissions to make this work!');
      }
    }
  }

  const pickImage = async () => {
    try{
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4,3],
      quality: 1,
    });

    if(!result.cancelled){
       //the storage itselg
    const storage = getStorage();

    const ref = ref(storage, `images/${result.uri}`)

    await uploadBytes(ref, result).then( (snapshot) => {
      alert('hello there')
    }).catch((error)=> {
      alert('error')
    });
  
    }

  }catch(error){
    alert(error.message)
  }
  }


  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={pickImage}>
      <Text>Select An Image</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Error

_ref3 is not a function. (In '_ref3(storage, "images/" + result.uri)', '_ref3' is undefined)

..........................................................................................